# Async Spring Rest Controller - Process future result

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I am new to futures and I am trying to figure out how I can process the Listenable future in this senario:

```
@Controller
@EnableAutoConfiguration
public class ListenableFutureAsyncController {

    @Autowired
    IHeavyLiftingService heavyLiftingService;

    @RequestMapping("/")
    @ResponseBody
    DeferredResult<String> home() {
        // Create DeferredResult
        final DeferredResult<String> result = new DeferredResult<>();

        //Call to the async service
        ListenableFuture<ResponseEntity<String>> future = heavyLiftingService.heavyLifting();

        future.addCallback(
          new ListenableFutureCallback<ResponseEntity<String>>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(ResponseEntity<String> response) {
                result.setResult(response.getBody());
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Throwable t) {
                result.setErrorResult(t.getMessage());
            }
        });
        // Return the thread to servlet container, 
        // the response will be processed by another thread.
        return result;
    }

}
```

How can I process the future here other than passing it back to the controller. Ex. What if I want to save the future string to the db?

```
@Service
public class HeavyLiftingServiceImpl implements IHeavyLiftingService {

    public ListenableFuture<String> heavyLifting() {
        AsyncRestTemplate asycTemp = new AsyncRestTemplate();
        ListenableFuture<String> future = asycTemp.execute(url, method, requestCallback, responseExtractor, urlVariable);
        /** 
        /Save future string to db
        **/
        return future;
    }
}
```

Comment: Why do you want to use a Future here?  Do you want the request to return right away, and then the save to occur later?

Comment: Imagine that the async template call took 10 seconds to run. I don't want the servlet thread to hold on to the thread for that long.

Comment: Are you expecting the client will have to make a second call to return the result?  I'm not sure there is a way to return the result without blocking on the servlet thread.

Comment: No, the deferred result will release the thread back to the servlet container in this example. When the result is available, the call back will be triggered and the response will be sent back to the caller. What I am trying to do is figure out how to perform additional processing on the result before the call back is called. I'm pretty sure this can be done. I'm just not sure how to chain the callbacks togethere correctly. Right now I'm looking at the transform method of Guavas Future class

Comment: Add a callback. I don't see a problem here.

Comment: Ah ok, I didn't know Spring supported this type of functionality with DeferredResult.  Good to know!   I would say that HeavyLiftingService should not be aware of ListenableFuture.  The Controller can create the future, and then, in the callback, it will call HeavyLiftingService.  This allows HeavyLiftingService to only be responsible for doing the "heavy lifting".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have found a way to do this using Spring's `ListenableFutureAdapter`

```
@Service
public class HeavyLiftingServiceImpl implements IHeavyLiftingService {

    public ListenableFuture<String> heavyLifting() {
        AsyncRestTemplate asycTemp = new AsyncRestTemplate();
        ListenableFuture<String> future = asycTemp.execute(url, method, requestCallback, responseExtractor, urlVariable);

        ListenableFutureAdapter<String, String> chainedFuture;
        chainedFuture = new ListenableFutureAdapter<String, String>(future) {

            @Override
            protected String adapt(String adapteeResult)
                    throws ExecutionException {
                        String parsedString = parse(adapteeResult);
                        return adapteeResult;
            }
        };

        return chainedFuture;
    }

}
```

I would recommend using Guava's implementation of listenable future. I find it more readable and documentation on chaining them together is easier to find.